# Can we still submit iOS app using xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard

I have an app on the app store that is compatible for iOS 4.0 and above. I built the app using xcode 4.2 on snow leopard 10.6.8 Now I want to make an update to my app. Can I submit the app using xcode 4.2? Or do I have to upgrade to mountain lion and download xcode 4.4.1 (I want my app to still be compatible with iOS 4.0 and above). I don't need any of the extra apis that iOs 6 brings, however I may use the cloud feature for iOS 5 (this is not a requirement). So can I still submit using xcode 4.2 to current app store?

Comment: I'm not certain of the answer to your question as posed, but even with the latest XCode you can still target iOS 4.0 if you need to.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Xcode 4.2 is the last version available for Snow Leopard, which is probably why he doesn't want to use a newer version of Xcode.

Comment: @Scott: Doesn't Apple require things like a 568h launch image for new submissions? I'm on the latest XCode so I'm not sure how it works for older versions.

Comment: @GregHewgill: I don't know if they actually _require_ them or not, but even if they do: you can always add one to your bundle. Xcode may be unaware of its significance, but once you download the app to a 4" device it'll work fine.

Comment: @Basri Every device that supports iOS 4.0 also supports 4.2.1. As mentioned, Xcode 4.4.1 is the last version of Xcode to supporting iOS 4.2.1 (later Xcode versions no longer compile for ARMv6). So if you don't mind insisting that your customers update their iOS, there is no reason you can't move to Xcode 4.4.1. That Xcode runs on Lion as well as Mountain Lion. Caveats… In that Xcode, you only get the simulator for iOS 4.3 -- but good enough for development while debugging on real 4.2.1 device. On M.Lion, you can only run Simulators for iOS 5, but again can use real 4.2.1 device for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Xcode 4.2 can still be used to submit apps to the App Store. I believe even 3.x versions can still be used, though the process is different then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I submitted using xcode 4.2 and it worked.

Comment: We're almost 2 years later now. Has anything changed? I'd assume we can no longer use XCode 4.2 to submit apps, but can we still make test builds of our apps?

Comment: I think you should still be able to use Xcode 4.2, if you add the right SDK. No idea why you would want that, it should still be possible.